# Mongoid equivalent of create_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Is there an equivalent of Active Records `Model.create_with` to pass creation parameters separate of find parameters in Mongoid?

```
# Find the first user named "Scarlett" or create a new one with
# a particular last name.
User.create_with(last_name: 'Johansson').find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Scarlett')
# => #<User id: 2, first_name: "Scarlett", last_name: "Johansson">
```

I find myself using a clunky workaround:

```
user = User.find_or_initialze_by(first_name: 'Scarlett')
user.update(last_name: 'Johansson') if user.new_record?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongoid's [`find_or_create_by`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria/Modifiable:find_or_create_by) takes an optional block which is only used when it needs to create something. The documentation isn't exactly explicit about this behavior but if you check the code you'll see that [`find_or_create_by`](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v4.0.2/lib/mongoid/criteria/modifiable.rb#L67) ends up as a call to this [`find_or`](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v4.0.2/lib/mongoid/criteria/modifiable.rb#L187) method:

```
def find_or(method, attrs = {}, &block)
  where(attrs).first || send(method, attrs, &block)
end
```

with `method` being `:create` and the `block` isn't used if the document you're looking for is found by `where`.

That means that you can say:

```
user = User.find_or_create_by(first_name: 'Scarlett') do |user|
  user.last_name = 'Johansson'
end
```

to get the effect you're after.

Presumably this "the `create` half uses the block" behavior is supposed to be obvious because `create` takes a block to initialize the object but `find` doesn't.

If you're paranoid about this undocumented behavior, you can include a check for it in your specs so you'll at least know when an upgrade breaks it.